# Extending a lombok annotation using Spring's meta-annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations, lombok

I recently discovered [lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) and I enjoy the comfort it's usage brings. There is only one particular thing I am missing.

So just out of curiosity: How could I extend the `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation in a way that it provides an additional default constructor to the class on which it is applied?

I was thinking of using Spring 4.0's capability to build [composed annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-meta-annotations), but I must admit I never programmed a custom annotation before. So I don't really know how to start ...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to extend the annotation, but if you want to add a default constructor, you can add the Lombok @NoArgsConstructor annotation.

Comment: My bad! I just have overseen the existence of that annotation. So it will be easy to compose an annotation using both, the AllArgs and the NoArgs annotation ...